# How to match a React node in @testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test if the prop is correctly enriched with a node value and then passed to a component. The problem is that, even if the test and the component have the same node, it is recognised as different by jest.

Basically, my component render the following:

```js
function MyComponent({columns}){
   let columnsWithDescriptions = columns.map(c => ({
      ...c,
      description: <div>{c.name} - {c.last_name}</div>
   });

   return <Table columns={columnsWithDescriptions} />
}
```

The in then test I execute:

```js
test('check props', function(){
   render(<MyComponent columns={[{name: 'abc', last_name: 'def'}]} />
   expect(Table).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
     columns: [{name: 'abc', last_name: 'def', description: <div>abc - def</div>}],
   }); 
});
```

It almost works but the fails because the node contains a different string inside:

```
                "description": <div>
        -         abc | def
        +         abc
        +          | 
        +         def
                </div>,
```

Do you have any suggestion in how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I've found the solution.
The assumption that the two elements are equal was wrong. In code:

```
const name = 'abc';
const last = 'edf';
<div> {name} - {last} </div> !== <div> abc - edf </div>
```

The first node has 3 children, the second node has just one child.

I fixed it in the test comparing:

```
<div> {name} - {last} </div> === <div> {'abc'} - {'edf'} </div>
```